# maven-buildnumber-plugin

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

i use the maven-buildnumber-plugin to generate my version number for JAR/WAR/EAR packages. So when doing a compile i'll get for example ${project.version}-${buildNumber}, because  is set to this value. But when using mvn deploy just ${project.version} is the filename, samen when i set  in pom.xml to XX ${buildNumber} then the filename ist file-XXX ${buildNumber} (<- not the content of buildNumber, instead ${buildNumber as test}). What do i do wrong? i also want to have the files installed with ${project.version} ${buildNumber}.

thx for any help

markus

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure I follow your question, but I had a problem getting a build number in my WAR manifest.  The discussion [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-993) helped me out.  I had to create a global property called build.version

```
<properties>
    <build.version>${project.version}-r${buildNumber}</build.version>
</properties>
```

and use that instead of using ${buildNumber} directly.  Hopefully that'll be some help with your problem.

Comment: V handy for Hudson/Jenkins too.  https://weblogs.java.net/blog/johnsmart/archive/2008/03/using_hudson_en.html  -  see archive section on maven ear plugin too.